# How to integrate 2 factor authentication with Google Oauth Login?

Tags: python, django, google-oauth

My Django web application is integrated with Google Oauth login. Even though I have enabled MFA for my email ID, I can log in to my website without confirmation for 2-factor authentication.

I want to extend the Google OAuth login feature in my webapp by adding 2-factor authentication. Does google provide any APIs to achieve this?

Comment: if google has added your device to trusted devices it wont ask for 2-factor authentication every time you login on that device.

Comment: Thanks, that answers my question. I revoked all the trusted devices for my email ID and the OAuth login asked me for confirmation for 2 factor authentication.